# Close button not closing the form

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a WinForms application written in VB originally and converted to C#. I am trying to debug my C# application by comparing with the VB counterpart.

What I notice, currently, is that the Topmost Right red color Cancel button in My C# application doesn't close the Form but it does in VB.

The **VB** code is here

```
Private Sub frmMain_FormClosing(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Dim Cancel As Boolean = eventArgs.Cancel
        Dim ErrorFlag As ErrorFlagType = InitErrorFlag()
        Dim UnloadMode As System.Windows.Forms.CloseReason = eventArgs.CloseReason
        Dim SavePath As String
        SavePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(ConfigSoftData.DirectoryData.AppPath, "Mold\lib")
        SaveSoftConfig(SavePath, ConfigSoftData, ErrorFlag)
        CheckDirectoryExists(SavePath)
        StatusText = ""
        eventArgs.Cancel = Cancel
        My.Settings.MainScreenLeft = Me.Left
        My.Settings.MainScreenTop = Me.Top
        My.Settings.MainScreenWidth = Me.Width
        My.Settings.Save()
    End Sub
```

The **C#** code is here

```
 private void frmMain_FormClosing(System.Object eventSender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            bool Cancel = eventArgs.Cancel;
            Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.ErrorFlagType ErrorFlag = FrontEndStructures.InitErrorFlag();
            System.Windows.Forms.CloseReason UnloadMode = eventArgs.CloseReason;
            string SavePath = null;
            SavePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(ModSoftFrontEndGlobalVariables.ConfigSoftData.DirectoryData.AppPath, "Mold\\lib");
            ModSoftConfiguration.SaveSoftConfig(ref SavePath,ref  ModSoftFrontEndGlobalVariables.ConfigSoftData,ref ErrorFlag);
           ModSoftCalculations. CheckDirectoryExists(ref SavePath);
            ModSoftFrontEndGlobalVariables.StatusText = "";
            eventArgs.Cancel = Cancel;
            Properties.Settings.Default.MainScreenLeft = this.Left;
           // My.Settings.MainScreenLeft = this.Left;
            Properties.Settings.Default.MainScreenTop = this.Top;
           // My.Settings.MainScreenTop = this.Top;
            Properties.Settings.Default.MainScreenWidth = this.Width;

            //My.Settings.MainScreenWidth = this.Width;

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

I think I am missing some event handler that would call this function on clicking the **Close** button in the form.

Comment: Have you bind this event to form "FormClosing" event or not?

Comment: how to bind this . Its WinForms not WPF else I would have directly added the function name in the form closing event. It would have been a cake walk

Comment: You use the Properties window in the designer to create or select an event handler, which you can do in VB as well.  There's no `Handles` clause so you must register the event handler explicitly, which is equivalent to `AddHandler` in VB.

Comment: wanted to know that I did what @sowjanyaattaluri has told.but its still not working for me

Comment: Take a look at the line "eventArgs.Cancel = ...", if you set it to true, then your form will not be closed. Default is false to close the form.

Comment: thats set to false only

Comment: If you run this on Win7 then you need to check the Output window.  If you see a "first-chance exception" message then you have [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a).

Comment: First of all:  could you set up a breakpoint (or debug printout) at `frmMain_FormClosing()` and check whether it actually gets executed?

Comment: yes it is getting executed

Comment: perhaps its taking too long to complete the tasks when closing, try adding one of those to the end of the closing `Application.Exit(); Environment.Exit(1);`

Comment: Check the Immediate Window when you attempt to close the form, make sure no exception is thrown. Also, what on earth are these supposed to do: `bool Cancel = eventArgs.Cancel;` and `eventArgs.Cancel = Cancel;`? You never change the `Cancel` variable, and even if you would it would still be better to call just `eventArgs.Cancel = true/false;` instead of declaring _another_ variable for it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind "frmMain_FormClosing" to FormClosing event like this,
click on form => properties => events,then

[image]

```
private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
      e.Cancel = false; // it will close the form
      e.Cancel = true; // it will not close the form     
}
```

Comment: I did but still the form is not getting closed

Comment: not working... dont know there is no Me.Close() in the VB code but the form is still closing

Comment: @Apoorv ´this.dispose()´?